# How do I specifiy class constraints for p in (:+:) f g p? (With :+: from GHC.Generics)

Tags: haskell, generics, types

To encode choice between constructors GHC.Generics defines the following type:

```
data    (:+:) f g p = L1 (f p) | R1 (g p)
```

The Generic class provides the method from to convert a Generic type to a representation:

```
from :: a -> Rep a x
```

To write a function that is type generic, I define a class that works on the representation:

```
class MyClass r where myFun :: r a -> Maybe Int
```

Assume I also have a class SomeClass for which I defined the instance:

```
instance (SomeClass (f p),SomeClass (g p)) => SomeClass ((:+:) f g p) where
  someFun (R1 _) = Just 42
```

How would I add a SomeClass constraint to an MyClass instance of the Generic sum type? In other words, what is wrong with the following instance:

```
instance (SomeClass (f p), SomeClass (g p), MyClass f, MyClass g)
      => MyClass ((:+:) f g) where
 myFun (L1 x) = myFun x
 myFun y      = someFun y -- Error: Could not deduce (SomeClass (f a))
                          -- arising from a use of ‘someFun’
```

A complete example I wrote is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, DefaultSignatures, DeriveGeneric, FlexibleContexts, 
             UndecidableInstances, AllowAmbiguousTypes, RankNTypes #-}
module M where
import GHC.Generics

---

class SomeClass a where 
  someFun :: a -> Maybe Int
  default someFun :: (Generic a, MyClass (Rep a)) => a -> Maybe Int
  someFun x = myFun (from x)

instance (SomeClass (f p),SomeClass (g p)) => SomeClass ((:+:) f g p) where
  someFun (R1 _) = Just 42

instance SomeClass Int where
  someFun i  = Just i

---

class MyClass r where 
  myFun :: r a -> Maybe Int

instance (SomeClass a) => MyClass (K1 i a) where
  myFun (K1 x) = someFun x -- This is fine

instance (SomeClass (f p), SomeClass (g p), MyClass f, MyClass g) => MyClass ((:+:) f g) where
  myFun (L1 x) = myFun x
  myFun y      = someFun y -- Error: Could not deduce (SomeClass (f a)) arising from a use of ‘someFun’
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? For `Generic` the parameter isn't really used. For `Generic1` it is the type parameter as in the `a` in `data Pair a = Pair a a` and is included in the `Rep1` as (ignoring metadata)  `Par1 :*: Par1`. Ignoring generics, `MyClass` requires a function from `r a -> Maybe Int` for all `a`; a function `SomeClass a => a -> Maybe Int` won't help you construct a function for all `a`, since it only works on some `a`s, those with a `SomeClass a => ` dictionary.

Comment: Adding a `SomeClass` constraint to the `MyClass` definition would be fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you add a `SomeClass a` constraint to `myFun` there's really nothing more to do.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Applicative
import GHC.Generics

class SomeClass a where
    someFun :: a -> Maybe Int

class MyClass f where
    myFun :: SomeClass a => f a -> Maybe Int

    default myFun :: (Generic1 f, MyClass (Rep1 f), SomeClass a) => f a -> Maybe Int
    myFun f = myFun (from1 f)
```

You can write instances for all of the data types used in generic representations. The most interesting of these is `Par1`, which actually uses the `SomeClass a` constraint to use `someFun` on an occurrence of the parameter.

```
-- occurences of the parameter
instance MyClass Par1 where
    myFun (Par1 p) = someFun p

-- recursions of kind *
instance SomeClass a => MyClass (K1 i a) where
    myFun (K1 a) = someFun a

-- recursions of kind * -> *
instance MyClass f => MyClass (Rec1 f) where
    myFun (Rec1 f) = myFun f

-- constructors with no arguments
instance MyClass U1 where
    myFun (U1) = Nothing -- or Just 0 or Just 1 depending on what you're doing

-- constructors with multiple arguments
instance (MyClass f, MyClass g) => MyClass (f :*: g) where
    myFun (f :*: g) = liftA2 (+) (myFun f) (myFun g)  -- or howerever you are going to combine the Maybe Int

-- data types with multiple constructors
instance (MyClass f, MyClass g) => MyClass (f :+: g) where
    myFun (L1 f) = myFun f
    myFun (R1 g) = myFun g

-- metadata
instance (MyClass f) => MyClass (M1 i c f) where
    myFun (M1 f) = myFun f
```

If you want to support composition of functors, we'll have to be a bit more clever. The obvious definition requires a `SomeClass (Maybe Int)` instance.

```
-- composition of functors
instance (MyClass f, MyClass g, Functor f) => MyClass (f :.: g) where
    myFun (Comp1 fg) = myFun $ fmap myFun fg
```

#### Deriving SomeClass from MyClass

We'll get `SomeClass` instances generically reusing `MyClass` to get them. Since `MyClass`'s `myFun` requires a `SomeClass` instance, we'll need to prove that the parameter `Par1` never occurs in a `Rep`. `from'` will prove that the parameter is empty.

```
class SomeClass a where
    someFun :: a -> Maybe Int

    default someFun :: (Generic a, MyClass (Rep a)) => a -> Maybe Int
    someFun a = myFun (from' a)
```

The `Void` type from [void](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/void) represents a type that can't logically exist. The following proves that the parameter for a `Generic` is always empty

```
-- Prove that the parameter is always empty
from' :: Generic a => a -> Rep a Void
from' = from
```

To satisfy the `SomeClass` constraint for `myFun` we equip `Void` with a `SomeClass` instance. We can be sure `someFun :: Void -> Maybe Int` is never called because there's no value of type `Void` to pass to it.

```
instance SomeClass Void where
    someFun = absurd
```

Now we can derive an instance for `SomeClass (Maybe Int)` assuming we have a `SomeClass Int` instance.

```
-- The following instances are needed for the composition of functors
instance SomeClass Int where
    someFun = Just

instance SomeClass a => SomeClass (Maybe a)
```

#### Deriving SomeClass

You don't need to reuse `MyClass` with `Void` to derive `SomeClass` instances. Instead you can define another class for things that have a `myFun` regardless of what the parameter is.

```
class GSomeClass f where
    gsomeFun :: f a -> Maybe Int
```

You'd write `GSomeClass` instances for everything except `Par1` and `Rec1` and use `GSomeClass` to derive `SomeClass` instances. The `Generic` instances never use the parameter, not even for types like `Maybe a`; instead each occurrence of the parameter `a` appears as a `K1 i a p`.

```
class SomeClass a where
    someFun :: a -> Maybe Int

    default someFun :: (Generic a, GSomeClass (Rep a)) => a -> Maybe Int
    someFun a = gsomeFun (from a)
```

Comment: You might want to mention that the (IMO, shady) reason `Generic` has an utterly useless type parameter `p` is that this allows `Generic` and `Generic1` to use the same representation types.

Comment: I think this is a somewhat shady reason because 1. It makes the simple version (`Generic`) much harder for new users of the library to use and 2. The minute you want `Generic2`, you find that the library doesn't provide it, and you'd need a whole new set of types to support it anyway.

Comment: @dfeuer It's not so much shady as boundry-pushing. Imagine that the types like `(f :+: g) p` are polykinded and that for `p :: k`,  `f` and `g` have the kind `k -> *`. When these were made, there weren't poly-kinded types, and even now there isn't a way (that I know of) to make a type level list of types of heterogeneous kinds.

Comment: Cirdec, I know my example is a bit contrived, but I don't think your solution would allow me to use the `someFun` instance for sum types.

Comment: @MaartenFaddegon I've added [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32743715/414413) that literally uses `someFun` in sum types. I doubt it is what you want and I suspect you misunderstand your problem. You will get higher quality answers that are more useful to everyone if you ask how to solve a real problem instead of asking how to solve an incidental problem you encountered trying to solve a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way in Haskell currently to write constraints of the kind `forall p. SomeClass (f p) =>` which is what you are trying to do in the type

```
(SomeClass (f p), SomeClass (g p), MyClass f, MyClass g) => MyClass ((:+:) f g)
```

There is a trick to capture those constraints with a second type class. You could write a second class `FSomeClass f` that represents `forall p. SomeClass (f p)`. If `SomeClass` is simple, you can just reproduce the fields of the dictionary for `SomeClass` in the dictionary for `FSomeClass`, using `f a` in place of `a` everywhere.

```
class FSomeClass f where
    fsomeFun :: f a -> Maybe Int
```

If `SomeClass` is more complicated, or if you need to provide a real `SomeClass` instance to code that depends on it, you can instead capture the entire `SomeClass` dictionary in a `GADT`. `Dict` captures a dictionary for any constraint.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

data Dict c where
    Dict :: c => Dict c
```

With `Dict`s we can write a class that says that, for every `a`, `f a` has a `SomeClass` instance trapped in a `Dict`.

```
class FSomeClass f where
    someDict :: p0 a -> p1 f -> Dict (SomeClass (f a))
    --          |       |       ^ there's a SomeClass (f a) instance
    --          |       ^ for this f
    --          ^ for any a
```

To get to the `SomeClass (f a)` instance you'd pattern match on the dictionary.

#### SomeClass and FSomeClass instances

We'll make `SomeClass (f p)` instances for all the types from `GHC.Generics` and `FSomeClass f` instances that demonstrate that `p` can vary over all types.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

For `Par1`, there's nothing we can do with the parameter `p`, since it can vary over all types. Our only other option is to provide no `SomeClass (Par1 p)` instance. For `Par1`, `K1`, and `U1` the `SomeClass` instances have no constraints and the `FSomeClass` instance just captures the `SomeClass` dictionary.

```
instance SomeClass (Par1 p) where
    someFun (Par1 p) = Nothing -- You can't do anything with the p; you know nothing about it.

instance FSomeClass Par1 where
    someDict _ _ = Dict

instance SomeClass a => SomeClass (K1 i a p) where
    someFun (K1 a) = someFun a

instance SomeClass a => FSomeClass (K1 i a) where
    someDict _ _ = Dict

instance SomeClass (U1 p) where
    someFun (U1) = Nothing -- or Just 0 or Just 1 depending on what you're doing

instance FSomeClass U1 where
    someDict _ _ = Dict
```

The `SomeClass` instances for `M1` and `Rec1` require a `SomeClass (f p) =>` constraint. Before we can construct a `Dict` for e.g. `SomeClass (Rec1 f p)` we have to introduce a dictionary for `SomeClass (f p)`. We get the dictionary from `SomeClass (f p)` from the `FSomeClass` instance for `f` and pattern match on its `Dict`.

```
instance SomeClass (f p) => SomeClass (Rec1 f p) where
    someFun (Rec1 f) = someFun f

instance (FSomeClass f) => FSomeClass (Rec1 f) where
    someDict pa _ = case someDict pa (Proxy :: Proxy f) of Dict -> Dict

instance SomeClass (f p) => SomeClass (M1 i c f p) where
    someFun (M1 f) = someFun f

instance (FSomeClass f) => FSomeClass (M1 i c f) where
    someDict pa _ = case someDict pa (Proxy :: Proxy f) of Dict -> Dict
```

For products and sums there are two constraints on the `SomeClass` instances, so we get and pattern match on two dictionaries. We'd handle composition of functors the same way, but I'm skipping it for brevity.

```
instance (SomeClass (f p), SomeClass (g p)) => SomeClass ((f :*: g) p) where
    someFun (f :*: g) = liftA2 (+) (someFun f) (someFun g)   -- or howerever you are going to combine the Maybe Int

instance (FSomeClass f, FSomeClass g) => FSomeClass (f :*: g) where
    someDict pa _ = case someDict pa (Proxy :: Proxy f) of
                       Dict -> case someDict pa (Proxy :: Proxy g) of
                           Dict -> Dict

instance (SomeClass (f p), SomeClass (g p)) => SomeClass ((f :+: g) p)  where
    someFun (L1 f) = someFun f
    someFun (R1 g) = someFun g

instance (FSomeClass f, FSomeClass g) => FSomeClass (f :+: g) where
    someDict pa _ = case someDict pa (Proxy :: Proxy f) of
                       Dict -> case someDict pa (Proxy :: Proxy g) of
                           Dict -> Dict
```

#### Using FSomeClass

With your original `MyClass`

```
class MyClass f where
    myFun :: f a -> Maybe Int
```

We'll write an instance for `:+:`. We'll take your original signature and replace `SomeClass (f p)` with `FSomeClass f`.

```
instance (SomeClass (f p), SomeClass (g p), MyClass f, MyClass g) => MyClass ((:+:) f g)
instance (FSomeClass f,    FSomeClass g   , MyClass f, MyClass g) => MyClass ((:+:) f g)
```

The branch for `R1` literally uses `someFun`.

```
instance (FSomeClass f, FSomeClass g, MyClass f, MyClass g) => MyClass (f :+: g) where
    myFun (L1 f) = myFun f
    myFun (R1 g) = case someDict g (Proxy :: Proxy g) of
                       Dict -> someFun g
```

I cannot recommend writing instances for `:+:` that are not associative. If you want to treat the first constructor differently, you should guarantee that later constructors won't be treated in the same way as the first constructor. A datatype

```
data MySum = A | B | C
```

Has more than one possible representation. Taking liberties with metadata, the two possible representations for `MySum` are

```
 A :+: (B :+: C)
(A :+: B) :+: C
```

The constructors' representations could be either of

```
L1 A      | R1 (L1 B) | R1 (L1 C)
L1 (L1 A) | L1 (R1 B) | R1     C
```